# Some tasks are not shown in the Tasks view in Eclipse (Spring Tool Suite)

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

Some TODOs from some files are not shown in the "Tasks" view in Eclipse. I performed a refresh and "Clean" on all projects and especially also on the affected project, done Maven > Update Project on the affected project. The Tasks view is configured to show all tasks. The TODOs from other XML files from other projects are shown in the "Tasks" view, but the TODOs from XML files from one project aren't. What's the reason? How to fix it?

I'm using the version 3.4.0.RELEASE of the Spring Tool Suite which uses the version 3.8.1 of the Eclipse platform.

Answer (score 0):

I found a **temporary** solution:

1. Go to Preferences > General > Editors > Structured Text Editors > Task Tags
2. Click "Clean and redetect Tasks"

This solved the problem and all TODOs are now visible.

However, **this solution has to be done each time, when a task isn't visible**. The problem is, that I may not know that a task isn't visible and therefore will have to clean and redetect tasks often, in order to see all current tasks. It already happened to me a couple of times that the tasks weren't refreshed and I had to repeat the aforementioned steps in order to refresh them. It's annoying. I would like the task view to be refreshed automatically. How can I do that? Is it a bug in Eclipse/STS, or what?